# What is the name for the unreachable part of a function's codomain?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, notation, linear-transformations, terminology

A function associates each element from a "domain" set/space with an element from a "codomain" set/space. It does not have to associate all the elements in the codomain. If it does use them all, it is "surjective".

I would like to know, what is the name for the set/space of elements in the codomain that are not used by a non-surjective function?

I am particularly interested in the context of linear mappings. The space I would like the name of is somewhat like the opposite of the nullspace.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: note that the complement of the image of a linear map is not a linear subspace, which may be why it is not often considered and not given a name.

Comment: @angryavian thank you. Yes, that is the exact property I am considering currently. I am trying to make a note that this space is lacking directional structure, which can be given by a Hilbert space structure and thus allow a pseudoinverse. For that reason I would like to name it. Then I realised I do not know the name for this space for general functions. It seems fundamental and I would like to know it.

Comment: Unfortunately "cokernel" is taken already.  :(

Comment: Maybe "co-image"?

Comment: @mweiss I believe cokernel is correct. You can make an answer of this if you choose.

Comment: @user83455 The cokernel is the *quotient* space of image w.r.t the range, not the *complement*.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you. I see that now, so it is a closer equivalent to the nullspace, which is useful to know. But it is not as I asked though, as you say: I don't see how it could refer to the unused range of general functions which is a shame. Maybe it can be useful: I see that cokernel is related to surjectivity, but my category theory is not enough to understand this, or know if the concept is applicable to arbitrary funcitons.

Answer (score 3):

Given a function $\DeclareMathOperator{\ran}{ran}f:A \to B$, I usually denote $A$ as the domain and $B$ as the codomain. The range of $f$ will always be a subset of the codomain (and will be equal to its codomain if it's surjective). The set you are interested in could just be written as $B\setminus\ran(f)$.

Formally, a function always associates at least one element of its domain to one element in its range. Since the range is defined to be $f(A) =\{f(a) : a\in A\}$ where $A$ is the domain. This formalism is not always distinguished to newer students in math.

Comment: "Codomain" is a better word than "range" because "range" is ambiguous. I will change the question. I usually use the word "image" as you use "range".

Comment: Since $f(A)$ is often used to denote the range of a function $f:A \to B$, you could also write this as $B\setminus f(A)$ or $B - f(A)$.

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain: I deleted my comment, sorry. $f(A)$ is used for the image of $f$, not the codomain. I'd say that this notation is fairly standard (e.g. it can be found in Baby Rudin).

Comment: @Joe now I agree with your comment!

Comment: This is a helpful answer. I can use $\text{codomain}(f) \setminus \text{ran}(f)$ as a closed formula expression. I will leave the question open though, because it would be good to find out about a more compact or canonical notation/word if there is one.

Comment: @user83455 I don’t think that a canonical notation nor name exists. This is not common enough, and “complement of the image” is sufficiently concise when it does come up.